# How can I get the UTC offset from a timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone-offset

In Node, how can I convert a time zone (e.g. `Europe/Stockholm`) to a UTC offset (e.g. `+1` or `+2`), given a specific point in time? [`Temporal`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html#Temporal-TimeZone) seems to be solving this in the future, but until then? Is this possible natively, or do I need something like [`tzdb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vvo/tzdb)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend not to use `tzdb` directly, but rather a date library that deals well with timezones. In particular, I found [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon) to be good for this, see [their documentation about timezone handling](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones). To get the offset, you just create a `DateTime` with the desired timezone, then get its [`.offset`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeoffset):

```
const dateInZone = DateTime.fromISO("2022-10-23T21:10:56Z", {
  zone: "Europe/Stockholm"
});
console.log(dateInZone.offset)
```

Alternatively, create a [`Zone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#zone) instance and get its [`.offset()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#zoneoffset) at a particular timestamp:

```
const zone = new IANAZone("Europe/Stockholm");
console.log(zone.offset(Date.parse("2022-10-23T21:10:56Z")));
```

Comment: For completeness: There is also a Temporal polyfill
https://github.com/js-temporal/temporal-polyfill

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to get the offset in hours and minutes using the [`ia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlingua) language, this will result in a UTC offset in the format GMT+HMM, `GMT+5:30` for example.

We can use a regular expression to get the HHMM offset, +5:30, -8:00 for example, this can be readily converted to a UTC offset in minutes.

I think in general it's best to use a library such as luxon to get the UTC offset (as shown in another answer), but it *can* be done in Vanilla JS.

```js
function getUTCOffsetHHMM(date, timeZone) {
    const fmt = date.toLocaleString('ia', { timeZoneName: 'longOffset', timeZone });
    return fmt.replace(/^.*? GMT/, '');
}

function getUTCOffsetMinutes(date, timeZone) {
    const hhmm = getUTCOffsetHHMM(date, timeZone);
    return parseHHMM(hhmm);
}

function parseHHMM(hhmm) {
    const [h, m] = hhmm.split(':').map(Number);
    return h * 60 + (m || 0) * (h < 0 ? -1: +1); 
}

const now = new Date();
const timeZones = ['America/Los_Angeles', 'America/St_Johns', 'Europe/Berlin', 'Asia/Kolkata', 'Asia/Tokyo'];
   
console.log('Timezone'.padEnd(22), 'UTC Offset (hh:mm)', 'UTC Offset (minutes)');
for(let timeZone of timeZones) { 
    console.log(timeZone.padEnd(22), getUTCOffsetHHMM(now, timeZone).padEnd(18), getUTCOffsetMinutes(now, timeZone)); 
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is, technically, the answer to my question, but it certainly seems worth using a lib for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, nothing native is available yet

Well, the list is well known, and easy to put in a hashmap

https://github.com/vvo/tzdb/blob/main/raw-time-zones.json

or use the library mentioned

Comment: Note: that list is not guaranteed to be correct "now", only when it was created. Because which places observe which time zones changes, and far more than you'd think.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your specific use case, but in general this should be the workflow:

1. Before you send date to the server, you send it in the ISO format (independent of the time zone). You can do it with native `new Date().toISOString()` method.
2. You save ISO date in the database.
3. Once it's returned to the client, you can parse ISO date which will automatically parse it to the user's local timezone.